# Make text appear/disappear on button click

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom-events

I'm trying to make the button alternate the text from hidden using 'none' to appear using 'block'. I tried the below but it did not work

```
<p id='demo' style = 'display: none'>Hello Javascript</p>     
<button type='button' onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.display='block'" >click me</ button>
```

I want to convert event listener to Javascript and run from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
function toggleText() {
  var text = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (text.style.display === "none") {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<p id='demo' style='display: none'>Hello Javascript</p>     
<button type='button' onclick="toggleText()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: If it'll help you out, please mark as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**css:**

```
.demo {
   display: none;
}
```

**html:**

```
<p id='demo' class='demo'>Hello Javascript</p>
<button type='button'> click me </button>
```

**js:**

```
var tag = document.getElementById('demo');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
tag.classList.toggle('demo');
});
```

Running Snippet:

```js
var tag = document.getElementById('demo');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
tag.classList.toggle('demo');
});
```

```css
.demo {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id='demo' class='demo'>Hello Javascript</p>
<button type='button'> click me </button>
```

Comment: i try to run your code but doesnt run and there was no error

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      .demo {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="demo" class="demo">hey</p>
    <button type="button">click</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var tag = document.getElementById('demo');
      var button = document.querySelector('button');

      button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        tag.classList.toggle('demo');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`

Comment: make sure the script tag is at the bottom of the document

Comment: is querySelector taking type button or the button tag?

Comment: querySelector is taking in the button tag

Answer (score 1):

Is it helpful:

```js
var showHide = document.getElementById("showHide");
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
showHide.onclick = function() {
  if (demo.style.display == "block") {
    demo.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    demo.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<p id='demo' style='display: none'>Hello Javascript</p>
<button id="showHide">Click Me</button>
```